# how can i get an attribute value of all links on a page?

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium

i'm trying to get a list of values of 'data-ctorig' property on all links marked with 'gs-title' class on [this](https://cse.google.com/cse?option=com_jumi&fileid=20&itemid=96&lang=pt-br&cx=011662445380875560067%3Acack5lsxley&cof=FORID%3A11&hl=pt-br&q=amanda&siteurl=www.teses.usp.br%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_jumi%26fileid%3D20%26Itemid%3D96%26lang%3Dpt-br&ref=&ss=431j40353j6&ad=n9&num=10&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teses.usp.br%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_jumi%26fileid%3D20%26Itemid%3D96%26lang%3Dpt-br%26cx%3D011662445380875560067%253Acack5lsxley%26cof%3DFORID%253A11%26hl%3Dpt-br%26q%3Damanda%26siteurl%3Dwww.teses.usp.br%252Findex.php%253Foption%253Dcom_jumi%2526fileid%253D20%2526Itemid%253D96%2526lang%253Dpt-br%26ref%3D%26ss%3D431j40353j6) page.

i can get one the value of first link 
`document.querySelector('a.gs-title').getAttribute('data-ctorig')` 
but can have others.
also, i can get a list of nodelist (idk what is this) using 
`document.querySelectorAll('a.gs-title')`
but i dont know how can i get a list of attribute values based in this node list.

also i've tried use :nth-of-type() but i got only null after first value

```
var x = document.querySelector("a.gs-title:nth-of-type(1)").getAttribute("data-ctorig")
```

i'm also using python with selenium webdriver to do this so if someone know how to do it on python 'll help me on the same way.

Comment: Use `.querySelectorAll()` and then iterate through the list it returns to build the final result array.

Comment: _"but i dont know how can i get a list of attribute values based in this node list."_ - Just do the same as you do with the result from `.querySelector()` for every element in the collection returned by `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Looking at [Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) docs, you can see there is a forEach method you can use to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use querySelectorAll to get all the .gs-title nodes.

```
var gstitles = document.querySelectorAll('a.gs-title')
```

You can use gstitles.length now to determine how many there are.

```
gstitles.length;
```

Next we need to setup a for loop.
Check out the code snippet below.

```
for (i=0;i<gstitles.length;i++) 
{
console.log(gstitles[i].getAttribute('data-ctorig'));
}
```

```js
var gstitles = document.querySelectorAll('a.gs-title')

for (i=0;i<gstitles.length;i++) 
{
console.log(gstitles[i].getAttribute('data-ctorig'));
}
```

```html
<div class="gs-title"><a class="gs-title" href="https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiWo7TB3-bhAhUF16wKHaWeCXoQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=011662445380875560067:cack5lsxley&amp;usg=AOvVaw2g3t_0fFH8wjhfjcku0DL3" data-ctorig="https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf"><b>AMANDA</b> PINTO DA FONSECA TOJAL</a></div><div class="gs-title gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail-left"><a class="gs-title" href="https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiWo7TB3-bhAhUF16wKHaWeCXoQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=011662445380875560067:cack5lsxley&amp;usg=AOvVaw2g3t_0fFH8wjhfjcku0DL3" data-ctorig="https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/27/27151/tde-19032008-183924/publico/AmandaTojal.pdf"><b>AMANDA</b> PINTO DA FONSECA TOJAL</a></div><div class="gs-title"><a class="gs-title" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/17/17153/tde-06012017-103806/publico/AmandaMizukamiDOCorrig.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiWo7TB3-bhAhUF16wKHaWeCXoQFggGMAE&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=011662445380875560067:cack5lsxley&amp;usg=AOvVaw0Jdjapa8W60DfKRyUIAdoH" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/17/17153/tde-06012017-103806/publico/AmandaMizukamiDOCorrig.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiWo7TB3-bhAhUF16wKHaWeCXoQFggGMAE&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=011662445380875560067:cack5lsxley&amp;usg=AOvVaw0Jdjapa8W60DfKRyUIAdoH" data-ctorig="http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/17/17153/tde-06012017-103806/publico/AmandaMizukamiDOCorrig.pdf"><b>AMANDA</b> MIZUKAMI</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You meant this? :)

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.gs-title');
var list = [];
links.forEach((link) => {
list.push(link.getAttribute('data-ctorig'));
});
console.log(list);
```

```html
<a class="gs-title" data-ctorig="Test1"><b>AMANDA</b> MIZUKAMI</a>
<a class="gs-title" data-ctorig="Test2"><b>AMANDA</b> MIZUKAMI</a>
<a class="gs-title" data-ctorig="Test3"><b>AMANDA</b> MIZUKAMI</a>
```

Comment: _"how can i get a **list** of attribute values"_

Comment: @Andreas My bad, i fixed it :)